# after upgrade from 1.7 to 1.9.1 order not saving after sagepay payments plus payment complete message not showing

Tags: magento-1.9, payment, payment-methods, sagepay

I have upgraded magento from 1.7 to 1.9.1. I have fixed paypal and it is all working and payment saving.

But Sagepay payments have 2 issues:

1) After payment has made it through Sagepay it redirects to shopping cart and ***no payment complete message*** is shown after paying. So the customer does not know if she has paid successfully.

2) The order created cannot be processed in the backend. However for Paypal it is saving properly. So only issue with Sagepay payment.

can anyone share his experience with this issue or offer an idea?

thanks

Comment: Have you checked if the Sagepay module you are using now is compatible with 1.9.1? Also might be a good idea to check with the developer if they have an updated version for 1.9.1. The issue would probably be fixed once you update the module.

Comment: Thanks Shaughn. Someone else did this website,  we don't want to go to them n I m bit new and learning.  The website we never updated for 2 years. We ask sagepay and they saying 169 pound to buy updated version,  which we can't afford. This use to work fine for 1.7 version. Any more comments to fix it. I m learning so need some further tips.  Thanks

Comment: I don't know a single other payment method that charges for the extension. Ask around Magento users in your country what they are using.This may be a good time to change vendors. That said - do you have programming experience in PHP? You may not be able to solve this otherwise.

Comment: Yeah that is strange. I m in UK. I know extension is free but this i did update from prev version and after it stopped working. I know php but not familiar with magento process. Sagepay seems to me rubbish so far. They charge us alot money and no support so far. I ll advice my client to move somewhere else like world pay.

Comment: can someone tell me if there is anything I do at backend setting to display message that 'Thanks  We have recieved your order. One of our representative will check and contact you shortly.'